# Какую БД выбрать для индексирования/кеширования данных?

Tags: java, nosql

Данные в большом кол-ве хранятся в кассандровом кластере. Ищу персистентную БД, в которую можно было бы стягивать часть данных (по ключу) и предоставлять клиенту, где бы он смог выполнять поиск по любым атрибутам (самый простой, типа name=Вася&age=18 etc) и сортировку (так же по любому набору атрибутов). С возможностью хранить в заранее отсортированном виде по определенному набору атрибутов (для каждого набора может быть свой).

Comment: ну насчет кеширования, то обычно за такое отвечают спец библиотеки типа гибернейта

Comment: Смотри в сторну http://www.ehcache.org/